# commitTransaction failed: CloseSafeProducer, Kafka transactions with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka

I am trying to use Kafka transactions along with multithreading.

Below code uses the executeInTransaction method:

```
public void postMessage(...) {
    kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(t -> {
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<Object, Object>> future = t.send(producerRecord);
        future.addCallback(new KafkaProducerCallback(topicName, key));
        return true;
    });
```

I have a list named someList whose content I want to publish to a topic. So I spin up a thread for each element in someList to publish it to kafka using the postMessage function above.

```
someList.forEach(some-> {
    BulkPublishThread bulkPublishThread = new BulkPublishThread(....);
    bulkPublishThread.start();
});
```

Here is the run method for the class extending the thread class:

```
public void run() {
    kafkaService.postMessage(...);
}
```

I am using multithreading to increase the speed as using kafka transactions take a lot of time.
I get the following error when I run my program.

`commitTransaction failed: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@404806a6, txId=tran-53] org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000milliseconds while awaiting EndTxn(COMMIT)`

`Error during some operation; producer removed from cache: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@404806a6, txId=tran-53]    [Producer clientId=tran-54, transactionalId=tran-53] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.    [Producer clientId=tran-54, transactionalId=tran-53] Proceeding to force close the producer since pending requests could not be completed within timeout 0 ms.`

`Exception in thread "Thread-97" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000milliseconds while awaiting EndTxn(COMMIT)`

The program runs fine when multithreading is not enabled.
The program runs fine when size of the someList is small but for larger list size ( around 200 ) it starts to show these error.
I tried setting the transaction.timeout.ms to 120000 and some greater values but it still show the same error "Timeout expired after 60000milliseconds while awaiting EndTxn(COMMIT)"

1. What could be the reason?
2. How do I solve it ?

Comment: Why you try to send single message within transaction? You can send whole list within one transaction. I don’t see whole code but my first impression is that your multi threading concept is simply wrong.

Comment: The list can be quite big sometimes ~1million items. Wouldn't sending them in the same transaction mean if even 1 message fails to publish then everything will be rolled back? I yes, this is not what I want. That is why I want to spin up multiple threads sending single messages within a transaction.

Comment: So imho you can use ack=all setting with proper min.in.sync.replicas value set on topic level and still I don’t see any need for transactions here.

Comment: I wanted to ensure exactly one delivery of my message and also wanted to consume only the messages that have been committed using isolation.level = read_committed in the consumer. Does ack = all and appropriate min.in.sync.replicas setting guarantee exactly once delivery ?

Comment: Yes, what you need to do is set `enable.idempotence=true` on producer's side and set `min.in.sync.replicas` to at least half plus one of topic's `replication.factor`, eg. `replication.factor=5` -> `min.in.sync.replicas=3`, that's all.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!